# Why did the Googlebot add "sp=1" to my URL's?

Tags: url, googlebot

Googlebot crawled my site for the first time today, and added something strange. It appended `&sp=1` to my URL's. It seems like it's trying to gain authorized access?

Normally I have `http://domain.com/?lang=en` and `http://domain.com/en`

What does this URL mean: `http://domain.com/?lang=en&sp=1`, why is `&sp=1` added to it?

The results with `&sp=1` are the same as the root page.

Comment: its an ad network adding in from what I've found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like either someone else is linking to you and appending these query parameters, or you have a link somewhere on your own site that is doing this. Googlebot doesn't just invent URLs to crawl. I suggest you add the following to as many pages as you can:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/this-page" />
```

A "canonical" link is the one that should be used by Google to link to the page. You would not include query parameters in it if they did not affect the output.

Comment: Okay, but I have properly URI as you defined without`sp=1` and also have a canonical URI `<link rel='canonical' href='http://domain.net/' />`. I think that some plugin affects on `sp=1`. I will research using GREP tool to find string `sp`, but what's about if none helped?

Comment: If you have the canonical link already in your HTML files, then you don't have to worry about Google crawling it with `&sp=1`, as Google will just save the normal URL. For tools to search through files, I recommend **BBEdit** on Mac OS X and **Notepad++** on Windows. Both of these can search recursively through a directory for text files, and scan those looking for RegEx patterns.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu dev and Debian server platform. I will used grep command instead. Thank you for help.

Comment: Possibly not helpful, but I've seen '&sp=1" on Facebook links, so perhaps you have a Facebook widget or links in your site somewhere.